# Ajax call in "for" loops skips odd/even iterations

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, callback

If I am here asking it is because we are stuck on something that we do not know how to solve. I must admit, we already searched in StackOverflow and search engines about a solution.. but we didn't manage to implement it / solve the problem.

I am trying to create a JavaScript function that:

- detects in my html page all the occurrences of an html tag: `<alias>`
- replaces its content with the result of an Ajax call (sending the
  content of the tag to the Ajax.php page) + localStorage management
- at the end unwraps it from `<alias>` tag and leaves the content returned from ajax call

the only problem is that in both cases it skips some iterations. 
We have made some researches and it seems that the "problem" is that **Ajax is asynchronous**, so it does not wait for the response before going on with the process. We even saw that "async: false" is not a good solution.

I leave the part of my script that is interested with some brief descriptions

```
// includes an icon in the page to display the correct change
    function multilingual(msg,i) {
         // code  
    }

    // function to make an ajax call or a "cache call" if value is in localStorage for a variable
    function sendRequest(o) {
        console.log(o.variab+': running sendRequest function');
        // check if value for that variable is stored and if stored for more than 1 hour
        if(window.localStorage && window.localStorage.getItem(o.variab) && window.localStorage.getItem(o.variab+'_exp') > +new Date - 60*60*1000) {
            console.log(o.variab+': value from localStorage');
            // replace <alias> content with cached value
            var cached = window.localStorage.getItem(o.variab);
            elements[o.counter].innerHTML = cached;

            // including icon for multilingual post
            console.log(o.variab+': calling multilingual function');
            multilingual(window.localStorage.getItem(o.variab),o.counter);

        } else {
            console.log(o.variab+': starting ajax call');
            // not stored yet or older than a month
            console.log('variable='+o.variab+'&api_key='+o.api_key+'&lang='+o.language);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: my_ajax_url,
                data: 'variable='+o.variab+'&api_key='+o.api_key+'&lang='+o.language,
                success: function(msg){
                    // ajax call, storing new value and expiration + replace <alias> inner html with new value
                    window.localStorage.setItem(o.variab, msg);
                    var content = window.localStorage.getItem(o.variab);
                    window.localStorage.setItem(o.variab+'_exp', +new Date);
                    console.log(o.variab+': replacement from ajax call');
                    elements[o.counter].innerHTML = content;

                    // including icon for multilingual post
                    console.log(o.variab+': calling multilingual function');
                    multilingual(msg,o.counter);
                },
                error: function(msg){
                    console.warn('an error occured during ajax call');
                }
            });
        }
    };

    // loop for each <alias> element found
        //initial settings
            var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('alias'),
            elem_n = elements.length,
            counter = 0;
            var i = 0;

    for(; i < elem_n;i++) {
        var flag = 0;
        console.info('var i='+i+' - Now working on '+elements[i].innerHTML);
        sendRequest({
            variab : elements[i].innerHTML,
            api_key : settings.api_key,
            language : default_lang,
            counter : i
        });

        $(elements[i]).contents().unwrap().parent();
        console.log(elements[i].innerHTML+': wrap removed');
    }
```

I hope that some of you may provide me some valid solutions and/or examples, because we are stuck on this problem :(

From our test, when the value is from cache, the 1st/3rd/5th ... values are replaced correctly
when the value is from ajax the 2nd/4th .. values are replaced

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't think that's the problem here.

Comment: On a second read of the code I think you're right.

Comment: Indeed @Pointy was right. But there is another little problem now (difference between datas from localStorage and from ajax)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `elements` array is a **live** NodeList. When you unwrap things in those `<alias>` tags, the element disappears from the list. So, you're looking at element 0, and you do the ajax call, and then you get rid of the `<alias>` tag around the contents. At that instant, `element[0]` becomes what *used* to be `element[1]`.  However, your loop increments `i`, so you skip the new `element[0]`.

There's no reason to use `.getElementsByTagName()` anyway; you're using jQuery, so use it consistently:

```
var elements = $("alias");
```

That'll give you a jQuery object that will (mostly) work like an array, so the rest of your code won't have to change much, if at all.

Comment: You are really amazing.. you deserve some chocolate cookies as a reward :)
Indeed that made me solve the first problem.. I already thought about that, but I didn't think that could be the problem.

**btw**, another "problem occurs": basically.. when localStorage is empty the content is not replaced with the result of the ajax call. While after a refresh everything works great (getting datas from localStorage).. any idea of why?

Comment: Oh OK I see. The problem is, again, with the `.unwrap()` call, but it's a different problem. You *start* the ajax call before you call `.unwrap()`, but it's not yet *finished*. Thus, you change the DOM so that the `<alias>` tag isn't there anymore. The old DOM node will still be there in the jQuery object, but because it's not part of the DOM anymore setting its contents doesn't have any visible effect. By contrast, the local storage access is synchronous.

Comment: You can move the `.unwrap()` stuff to inside that routine that gets content from local storage or ajax. If the code decides to do the ajax call, it should perform the unwrapping in the "success" callback after it's updated the contents.

Comment: Thank you @Pointy - you helped me a lot !

Answer (score 0):

To solve issues like this in the past, I've done something like the code below, you actually send the target along with the function running the AJAX call, and don't use any global variables because those may change as the for loop runs. Try passing in everything you'll use in the parameters of the function, including the target like I've done:

```
function loadContent(target, info) {
    //ajax call
    //on success replace target with new data;
}
$('alias').each(function(){
    loadContent($(this), info)
});
```